# How to extend the lifetime of one shared_ptr to that of a second std::shared_ptr in c++

Tags: c++17, shared-ptr

I have an annoying library struct that holds an object by reference.

```
struct B {
    A & a;
    B(A & pA):a(pA){}
}
```

I would like to hold a `std::shared_ptr<B>` but also extend the lifetime of `a` so that I don't have to manually hold it. Assume `A` is

```
struct A {
    int i;
    A(int i):i(i){}
};
```

Assume I already have a shared_ptr to an 'A'. If I dod

```
auto b = std::make_shared<B>(a)
```

but don't hold onto `a` then I will get a dangling reference. However I don't really need my `a` object anymore. I would like the lifetime of `a` to be tied to the lifetime of `b`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the custom deleter of the std::shared_ptr like so

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
    int i;
    A(int i):i(i){}
};

struct B {
    A & a;
    B(A & pA):a(pA){}
};

/// @param a the pointer to attach another pointer to
/// @param b the pointer whose lifetime we wish to extend
/// @return the same pointer to a but with a deleter that extends the lifetime of b
template <typename A, typename B>
std::shared_ptr<A> attach_ptr(std::shared_ptr<A> const & a, std::shared_ptr<B> const &b)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<A>(a.get(),[a,b](auto){});
}

std::shared_ptr<B> MakeB(int i){
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>(i);
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>(*a);
    return attach_ptr(b,a);
}

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<B> b = MakeB(19);
    MakeB(0);
    return b->a.i;
}
```

The provided code demonstrates the use of a custom deleter for a shared pointer in C++, which facilitates extending the lifetime of a pointer. Specifically, the attach_ptr function employs the special constructor of the std::shared_ptr, which takes a custom deleter as a parameter. The custom deleter can be any function, but in this case, a lambda function is used to capture by value two input shared_ptr instances, incrementing their reference counts. The raw pointer from the first shared pointer is used as the actual pointer held by the new shared pointer, allowing it to behave like std::shared_ptr.

By utilizing this custom deleter mechanism, it is possible to extend the lifetime of a pointer beyond the scope of its original shared_ptr. The MakeB function showcases this technique by creating two shared pointers to instances of classes A and B respectively, and attaching the shared pointer of A to the shared pointer of B using the attach_ptr function. Consequently, the lifetime of A is extended to match the lifetime of B.

When the last reference to the output shared_ptr is lost, the control block is erased, and the two held values are also erased, decrementing their reference counts. Overall, the custom deleter in attach_ptr enables the extension of the lifetime of a shared pointer, ensuring the integrity and safety of the program.

https://godbolt.org/z/hzexbMv7a